# Looping through JavaScript object tree and displaying it like in Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'd like to implement in one of my projects a JavaScript object and display all the values like it is shown e.g. in Chrome Developer Tools:

[image]

Does anybody know a **library** or **at least some good code-snippets** to achieve that without re-inventing the wheel?
I am using AngularJS, so a directive would be nice ...

Regards
Stefan

Answer (score 0):

With just a small amount of styling, you could use an Angular / Bootstrap ***Dropdown*** approach ::

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Answer (score 0):

Did you try use json filter in view ?

js :

....

```
$scope.layout = {clientVersiong:"", ....}
```

HTML:

```
<pre>{{layout | json }}</pre>
```